# Cargar de datos GridControl DevExpress mediante un DataTable

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms, devexpress

Estoy usando *Windows Forms*, *GridControl DevExpress*, *SQL Server 2008*.

Intento cargar de datos un *GridControl* por medio de un *DataTable*. El código es el siguiente:

```
var dtDatos = GetAll("SELECT EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, Address FROM Employees");
if (dtDatos.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    for (int Nro = 0; Nro < dtDatos.Rows.Count; Nro++)
    {
        ;
    }
}
```

La variable `dtDatos` es el *DataTable* que me trae los registros desde la base de datos, y mediante el `for` intento llenarlo de datos, pero el problema es que no sé qué propiedades se usan en un *GridControl*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No veo por qué realizar la asignación de los datos a mano, cuando puedes enlazar directamente el GridControl a la fuente de datos valiéndote de su propiedad [DataSource](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridGridControl_DataSourcetopic), por ejemplo:

```
gridControl1.DataSource = dtDatos
```

Para ejemplos y tutoriales, no dejes de ver la sección del manual [Binding to Data](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument634).

Comment: Hola jachguate es que donde laboro lo cargan de esa manera no usan mucho el DataSource es que agregan filas al control y si esta conectado a una fuente de datos no se podría.

Answer (score 2):

Según la siguiente página, que forma parte de la documentación d DevExpress, un *GridControl* tiene las siguientes propiedades.

https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraGridGridControltopic

```
EditorContainer, IPrintableEx, IPrintable, IBasePrintable, IPrintHeaderFooter,
INavigatableControl, IToolTipControlClient, ISupportLookAndFeel, IDXManagerPopupMenu,
IViewController, IFilteredComponent, IFilteredComponentBase, IBoundControl,
ISupportXtraSerializer, IGestureClient, IGuideDescription,
IFilteredComponentColumnsClient, ISearchControlClient, IFilteredComponentColumns,
y ILogicalOwner`
```

Answer (score 0):

Siempre y cuando tu grilla en el .aspx coincida con la data buscada en BD (mismos nombres).-

```
var dtDatos = GetAll("SELECT EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, Address FROM Employees");

if (dtDatos.Count > 0)
{
  grilla.DataSource = dtDatos;
  grilla.DataBind();

}
```